# What are the pros and cons of using vh versus vw for responsive text?

Tags: html, css, text, flexbox

I guess what my question really boils down to is this: There are many different ways of making text responsive, but why use one over the other? Is there a method that is best for general use or do the different techniques have different uses?

Comment: `vw` and/or `vh` units

Comment: Questions seeking help must include a desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: CSS doesn't do this, but you can take a look at vmin and vmax units

Comment: @GCyrillus Hey, yeah I just updated my question. vmin and vmax seems to be the preferred way of doing things now right? Is there a reason for that over em/rem methods?

Comment: maybe the best is to search for their meaning/use ? https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

Comment: I've edited my question to be more specific. I'm trying to go through my previous questions and make them better. Can this question be answered now?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, font size units vh and vw will make the font size relative to viewport height and width, respectively.

Increase/decrease the pane in the lower right (output) window of [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/k3qj5tqh/) to see it work.

Better info here at [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) and [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

**More Stuff**

[@media (breakpoints) @ w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

[meta viewport @ w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

[meta viewport at css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/)

```css
p:first-child {
  font-size: 4vw
}
p:last-child{
  font-size: 6vh
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>This text will expand or contract based on the viewport width.</p>
  <p>This text will expand or contract based on the viewport height.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the link. So I've used vh and vw before, and I've reformatted my question to reflect this, but why would one use vh over vw or visa versa? I see both being used in the CSS tricks article but I'm not clear on what purpose that serves.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of viewport units and @media tags. Try resizing this after clicking expand snippet.

```css
p {
  font-size: 2vw;
}
```

```html
<p>
  fawef faw ef afwe awojeif poiaj fojaw oefj aoijf ojia faowjif aojiwfeoja ojfoj owaj fja pfija ijfaowij jva jevsoij iwefjiwap4hwt4awjiajfoi jo ijfaowj oiej poifjaew ofjei
</p>
```

More sources:

- https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Answer (score -3):

Can't you just use media queries.

Comment: Don't post comments as questions, be patient and answer questions that does not need clarifications until you have enough reps. to comment

Comment: Could you give examples of this @MarkM?